# Registre du mot "palpable"

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, registre

Je me demande quel est le registre du mot *palpable*. De plus, est-ce un mot courant (usage figuratif) ? Par exemple :

> L’énergie potentielle est stockée avec l’interaction entre deux objets liés par
>   une force conservative. À l’échelle macroscopique, la forme la plus **palpable**
>   est l’énergie potentielle de pesanteur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est un mot de registre langue courante ; c'est un mot que l'on trouve assez souvent et qui s'emploie aussi dans la langue parlée ; il a deux acceptions connectées et  proches l'une de l'autre ;

> II. Au fig.
>   A. [En parlant d'une chose gén. abstr.] Qui peut être appréhendé par l'esprit dans sa nature profonde, dans son authenticité, dans son exactitude, etc., notamment grâce à des moyens d'expression particulièrement évocateurs ou précis.
>
> - L'objet du livre : rendre au monde son âme qu'il cherche, la lui rendre visible et palpable, pour ainsi dire, la lui mettre dans la main.
> - Plus ses projets prenaient une forme nette, palpable, matérielle, plus complètement il se représentait tous les détails d'une nouvelle vie.
> - Choses de l'intelligence que ce théâtre nous rend palpables et cerne avec des signes concrets.
>
> B. Qui peut être appréhendé, admis intellectuellement grâce à un raisonnement, à des signes irréfutables. Synon. **certain, contrôlable, incontestable, manifeste, vérifiable**; anton. **contestable, douteux, faux, hypothétique, incertain, incontrôlable, problématique**
>
> - Un exemple aussi clair, aussi palpable, aussi aisé à vérifier.
> - Preuves irrécusables, palpables, éclatantes, devant lesquelles le doute s'évanouit forcément.
> - Cela vous est égal qu'il soit patent, palpable, Évident, que Chloris vous adore.

Ce que je me demande, c'est laquelle des deux est vraiment celle qui convient dans le cas présent. Il semblerait que l'échelle macroscopique étant le domaine de ce que l'on peut contempler à l'œil nu, donc les masses en hauteur, les ressorts comprimés et ainsi de suite, lesquels confèrent par expérience générale  à notre esprit la notion d'énergie  potentielle, il s'agirait ici de l'acception « B. » ; cela donne cependant matière à discussion et devrait être reconsidéré, en particulier par le physicien selon son optique particulière, bien que les deux acception, pour me répéter, sont assez proches (c'est à dire que l'on pourrait peut être négliger la nuance faite par le dictionnaire).

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit d'un adjectif et oui il est assez courant.

Plus d'infos sur le site du CNRTL: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/palpable